# Equivalent of `break` in purrr::map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Say I want to run a loop until a condition is met, at which point the result is saved and the loop exits:

```
library(tidyverse)

for (i in 1:5) {

  df <- iris %>% select(i) %>% head(2)

  if (names(df) == "Petal.Width") {
    out <- df
    break 

  }
}

out
```

How can I rewrite this using `purr::map` without having to evaluate each i?

Doing the following gives the result I need, but has to evaluate 5 times, whereas the for loop only 3 times:

```
fun <- function(x) {

  df <- iris %>% select(x) %>% head(2)

  if (names(df) == "Petal.Width") {
  return(df)
  }
}

map_df(1:5, fun)
```

Comment: If you need a `break` you're not going to be able to use `map`. The `map` functions are optimized to return a vector the same length as the input. They are not replacements for loops, just convenience functions for the most common uses of loops.

Comment: There might be a hacky way to use `purrr::possibly` or `purrr::safely` with a `stop` call inside the function, but as @KonradRudolph says below, it's probably not a great idea or the purpose of those helper functions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no equivalent. In fact, one thing that makes `map` (and similar functions) so superior to general loops in terms of readability is that they have absolutely predicable behaviour: they will execute the function exactly once for each element, no exceptions (except, uh, if there’s an exception: you could raise a condition via `stop` to short-circuit execution, but this is *very rarely* advisable).

Instead, your case doesn’t call for `map`, it calls for something along the lines of `purrr::keep` or `purrr::reduce`.

Think of it this way: `map`, `reduce`, etc. are abstractions which correspond to specific special cases of the more general `for` loop. Their purpose is to make clear *which* special case is being handled. As a programmer, your task then becomes to find the *right* abstraction.

In your particular case I would probably completely rewrite the statement using dplyr so giving a “best” purrr solution is hard: the best solution is not to use purrr. That said, you could use `purrr::detect` as follows:

```
names(iris) %>%
    detect(`==`, 'Sepal.Width') %>%
    `[`(iris, .) %>%
    head(2)
```

Or

```
seq_along(iris) %>%
    detect(~ names(iris[.x]) == 'Sepal.Width') %>%
    `[`(iris, .) %>%
    head(2)
```

… but really, here’s dplyr for comparison:

```
iris %>%
    select(Sepal.Width) %>%
    head(2)
```

Comment: Anecdote time, I’m currently working on a piece of code that does exactly what I’ve advised against: it signals a condition from inside an `lapply`. I *think* it’s appropriate in my situation but I’m not really sure.

Comment: Could you help rewrite using `keep` or `reduce`?

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks - it's actually from a web scraping exercise where I am scraping multiple tables on each page & checking if a condition is met. It's too complex to post so I simplified it to what the essence of my problem is

Answer (score 3):

**1)** `callCC` can be used to get this effect:

```
callCC(function(k) {
  fun2 <- function(x) {
    print(x) # just to show that x = 5 is never run
    df <- iris %>% select(x) %>% head(2)
    if (names(df) == "Petal.Width") k(df)
  }
  map_df(1:5, fun2)
})
```

giving:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
  Petal.Width
1         0.2
2         0.2
```

**1a)** If it is important to use `fun` without change then try this instead:

```
callCC(function(k) map_df(1:5, ~ if (!is.null(df <- fun(.x))) k(df)))
```

**2) purrr::reduce** An alternative is to use `reduce` from purrr (or `Reduce` from base R):

```
f <- function(x, y) if (is.null(x)) fun(y) else x
reduce(1:5, f, .init = NULL)
```

This is not as good as (1) and (1a) from the viewpoint that it will still involve iterating over each element of 1:5 but will only invoke `fun` for 1:4.  In contrast (1) and (1a) actually return after running `fun` or `fun2` on 4.